# How to pass complex get parameters in Angular 4 http?

Tags: angular, http

I need to pass these parameters via get http request in Angular 4.

[image]

I tried this code:

```
let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    for (var key in query) {
        if (query.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            let val = query[key];
            params.set(key, val);
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't work.

What is the good way to do that?

Comment: What's your current behavior ? Could you try with `params.append` instead of .set please ?

Comment: can you share more code for your example? What about this:
 return this._HttpClient.get(`${API_URL}/api/v1/data/logs`, {
        params: new HttpParams().set('logNamespace', logNamespace)
    })

?